# Why declare analog pins as ints?

Tags: pins, variables

I often see code like this:

```
const int piezo = A0;
const int sensorPin = A1;
```

From my understanding, an int variable can hold things like -123, 0, 1, 456, etc.

How can A0 or A1 be an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board definition (pins_arduino.h) has this:

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 14;
static const uint8_t A1 = 15;
static const uint8_t A2 = 16;
static const uint8_t A3 = 17;
static const uint8_t A4 = 18;
static const uint8_t A5 = 19;
static const uint8_t A6 = 20;
static const uint8_t A7 = 21;
```

Since A0 is a constant variable equal to 14, if you assign that to a variable, it just assigns 14.

In other words:

```
A = 14.
B = A.
Therefore B = 14.
```

Answer (score 1):

They are defined in the Arduino libraries, and the Arduino libraries will translate them into the appropriate pins and registers before they are used. But in the meantime they're numbers.